# Resource Dictionary WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a resource dictionary in my WPF application which contains the style information for the various controls.

Can it be used like the way we use in CSS in HTML? For example

```
 p
 {
   margin:20px;
   font:Tahoma;
  }
```

this applies to all "p" tags in HTML. We dont have to specifically mention that in the HTML for "p" tag.

Is the same approach applicable in WPF, or do we have to specifically 
mention the style

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" Style="{DynamicResource SomeTextblockStyle}" />
```

in the XAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly set a default style for each type. You can do this within your `Generic.xaml`, note that I am not providing a key.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

This will style every instance of a `Button` within your application as such.

If you were go to a XAML file and define an instance of a `Button`, overriding the `Foreground` value, that local instance will take precedence over the global style.

```
<Button Foreground="Black"/>
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the reply, it worked, but if I apply a style to a textblock, it will change everything including the menuitems. is there any solution for this?

Comment: It's all about hierarchy, sony. You might need to style the next level of embedded object to "reset" things. If you set a Form's foreground color, a TextBlock that inherits that property from its parent object will use that Form's foreground color.

Comment: @sony As djdanlib mentions, this all relates to hierarchy. The one closest to the implementation wins. If you apply a local style to a TextBlock which has a global style in place and you are expecting the global style to stay in place, this won't happen. It would go against the natural flow of precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You can set style like using key

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="myStyle">
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
</Style>
```

And in the Window.Xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello" Style="{DynamicResource myStyle}"/>
```